# A computation of nearby cycles

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

I'm currently reading P.Scholze's paper "THE LANGLANDS-KOTTWITZ APPROACH FOR THE MODULAR
CURVE". In Lemma 7.7, he showed a (maybe simple) nearby cycle computation, which I can't follow.

Now let me introduce the situation.

Let $K$ be a local field with residue characteristic $p$, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ and residue field $k$. Fix a prime number $l\neq p$. Let $H$ be a finite group, we can consider the following derived functor
$$\mathrm{R}_{I_K}:\mathrm{D}^{b}({\mathrm{Rep}_\overline{\mathbb{Q}_l}}(G_K\times H))\rightarrow \mathrm{D}^{b}({\mathrm{Rep}_\overline{\mathbb{Q}_l}}(G_k\times H)).$$
$G_K$(resp. $G_k$) is the absolute Galois group of $K$(resp. $k$). Both sides are the bounded derived category of finite dimentional continuous $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l$-representations of the mentioned group. Let $I_K$ be the inertia group of $K$. Then $\mathrm{R}_{I_K}$ is the right derived functor of taking ${I_K}$-invariants.

Now let $V_0$ be a finite dimentional continuous $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l$-representations of $G_K\times H$ such that $I_K\times 1$ **acts through a finite cyclic quotient**. Then the computation in the lemma claims that $\mathrm{R}_{I_K}(V)$ can be represented by a complex
$$\cdots\rightarrow0\rightarrow0\rightarrow V^{I_K}\stackrel{0}\rightarrow V^{I_K}(-1)\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow\cdots.$$

I'm confused about this fact. Can anyone offer me some help? Very thanks!

**Edit:** I think I might understand somewhat the geometric meaning of the claim, but I can't turn the intuition into a rigorous proof in this case. Namely, when we derived-pushout a constant sheaf along $\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and then take the stalk at the origin, the result complex has exactly the same shape of the one in the question.